# symfony collection - add one item at once

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine

I have a collection with a oneToMany relation. Now instead of using the whole prototype and javascript implementation according to the official [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), **I'd like to be able to add just one item to the collection at once**. Ideally by using e customType instead of the CollectionType but Symfony does not seem to allow it. Furthermore I'd like to avoid hacking around in the Controller.

Does anybody have a good idea to implement this?

Comment: Do the same of the cookbook, but modify the js code for removing the add button after the insert. That make sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that you want to add one item at a time and avoid JavaScript, why not something like a function that has a form that handles a single instance of your related object.

For instance, when you do the add/create function, create a new object and just set the related value of the object and pass that to the form.

Example;
Class Foo is one, class Bar is many

```
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->setFoo(1);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($bar)
            ->add('whatever', TextType::class)
            -->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Bar for Foo'))
            ->getForm();
```

After successful form, redirect back to where you want; either another add form or a list of your parent class.
This is really nothing more then a basic example of how [Symfony handles forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html), you are just creating a new object, pre-setting some of the values.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. Yes this might be the solution. I was hoping there is a way without having to pre set the data. hence without the `$bar->setFoo(1);`
I guess this isn't possible